# Google Cloud Composer | Airflow - Specifying or closing maintenance windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Airflow with Cloud Composer. I have a Dag scheduled to work every hour. However, I read something like this in the [composer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/specify-maintenance-windows): **"Maintenance operations might impact the execution of your DAGs and Airflow tasks"**

But the cron job I created should run for every hour. I don't want any downtime due to maintenance windows.
I'm worried about any problems with the selected maintenance windows. Can you give me information about this? Do I have an option to close the maintenance window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify what you meant at "close the maintenance window" is to remove maintenance windows? If you mean is to specify/adjust the maintenance window, steps to do that is already present on your question which is specified this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/specify-maintenance-windows).

Comment: @Ricco D The DAG I created should run every hour.  I cannot define start_time and schedule_interval values outside of maintenance window time. Because cloud composer requires to define maintenance windows 12 hours a week. I'm worried about the DAG running at maintenance window time. Actually there is no problem right now, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, running DAGs on the maintenance window might cause scheduling or execution issues. This was also mentioned in [Cloud Composer Troubleshooting Scheduler issues](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-scheduling#avoid_task_scheduling_during_maintenance_windows).

> You can define specific maintenance windows for your environment.
> During these time periods, maintenance events for Cloud SQL and GKE
> take place.
>
> Avoid scheduling DAG runs during maintenance windows because this
> might cause scheduling or execution issues.

Also removing the maintenance window won't be considered as a feature moving forward as per [Cloud Composer Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/204179972).

> Information from the Engineering team is that this feature is not in
> the road map. Hence, We're not going to have this feature in the
> future to remove the maintenance window once it's applied to the
> composer environment.
>
> Reason: If Environment don't have any maintenance windows then
> maintenance operations are happening at random times and having
> maintenance window allows to have maintenance operations in
> predictable slots.

Unfortunately your only option is to deal with the scheduling or execution issues if ever you encounter one. Since you have mentioned that your DAG runs every hour.